# Conflict between a Directive and a Service($resource) with AngularJS

Tags: resources, angularjs, directive

I'm newbie in angularJS world and I probably misunderstand something.

My app use controllers, directives and services, all run perfectly untill I use a service with $resource, then there is a "conflict" or something else wrong.

**Working directive :**

```
myApp.directive('components', function(){
    return function(params){
        [...]
    }
});
```

**Working service :**

```
myApp.factory('myFactory', function(){
    return{
        [...]
    }
});
```

**Service that cause the trouble :**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']).factory('resourceFactory', function($resource){
    return{
        [...]
    }
});
```

There is no error in the console, the service with $resource works but the directive seems not executed.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Are you defining 'myApp' twice?  I'm concerned that the 1st factory and 2nd factory are defined in a totally different way, why?

Comment: You got the point, the second way cause the trouble I think. But this is the the only way I found to use $resource (see the first comment in official documentation http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource).

Comment: module dependency comes into module definition.  Not the service/directive/etc.. definition.  So you just have to define module dependency when creating module once.  I posted the answer to show sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to define `myApp` in following way.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);
```

then define service/directive/controller on it.

```
myApp.controller(...)
myApp.directive(...)
myApp.factory(...)
```

Comment: That during the thousand years your name is mentioned with respect! Thanks!